# Identifier Node* is undefined(linker problem)

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-construction, header-files, return-type

I am really sorry if this is a duplicate post, but I am really stuck on this particular problem. For some inexplicable reason the compiler does not understand what return type Node* is on the .cpp file, here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
Node* BinarySearchTree<T>::DiveDownToReplace(Node* node) {
    if (node->leftChild->rightChild == nullptr) {
        return node->leftChild;
    }
    //otherwise
    Node* traversingNode = node->leftChild;
    Node* returnedNode;
    while (true) {
        if (traversingNode->rightChild->rightChild == nullptr) {
            returnedNode = traversingNode->rightChild;
            traversingNode->rightChild = returnedNode->leftChild;
            returnedNode->leftChild = nullptr;
            break;
        }
        traversingNode = traversingNode->rightChild;
    }
    return returnedNode;

}
```

Here is also the code in the .h(header file):

```
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class BinarySearchTree {
private:

    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* leftChild;
        Node* rightChild;
    };

    int m_Length = 0;
    Node* root = new Node();

public:
    enum class TraverseMethod
    {
        preorder,
        inorder,
        postorder,
        levelorder
    };

    ~BinarySearchTree();
    void AddElement(T value);
    T RemoveRoot();
    bool RemoveElement(T value);
    void PrintAllElements(TraverseMethod traverseMethod);
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool GetSize();
    bool Contains(T value);

private:

    void PreOrder(Node* node);
    void InOrder(Node* node);
    void PostOrder(Node* node);
    void LevelOrder(bool deleteNode = false);
    void DiveDownToAdd(T value, Node* node);
    Node* DiveDownToReplace(Node* node);
};
```

I am getting the error "identifier Node is undefined". I tried adding BinarySearchTree::Node* instead of Node*, but I received some weird errors(c2061, syntax error: identifier 'Node'). Once more I am sorry if this post is duplicate, but coming from languages like c# and Java I am really fed up with these header issues. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you included the header?

Comment: You almost got it right, you should've added `typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *` instead of `Node *`.

Comment: *"I tried adding BinarySearchTree::Node\* instead of Node\*"* - When you tried expanding the full template definition in your prior attempt, you prefaced the dependent subtype with `typename`, *right* ? I.e. `typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node` ? Unrelated, best to find out now rather than later that a .cpp file is *probably* not where you want a template function or class member implementation residing.

Comment: yes I added the header(I should have shown that, my mistake ). It seems that "typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *" is working. Give me a second to make sure. Thank you all!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and whozcraig(I am not allowed to tag 2 people) it seems to be working fine with "typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *", thank you for your help! Could any of you post the answer(I do not think I can credit a comment). Otherwise I will post the answer. Again I know that this problem was probably trivial, but I got really tired of these header stuff. In any case thank you all for your help!

Comment: @WhozCraig everywhere on the web I have seen people separating a class in 2 files(a .cpp with the implementations and .h with the declarations). Is that wrong? Could you link me a source that says otherwise?

Comment: @WhozCraig can/should I delete the question then(I thought that this might be a duplicate )?

Comment: Leave it. I'll mark it as a dupe.

Comment: To answer your other question to me, read this: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two rather complicated technical details of C++ that get combined together here. First of all, is scoping and namespaces.

```
    //otherwise
    Node* traversingNode = node->leftChild;
```

This is code that's inside a member function of the `BinarySearchTree` template. When a symbol, such as `Node` gets used the compiler needs to know what in blazes is that. `BinarySearchTree` defines an inner class named `Node`, so there you go. Problem solved.

```
template<typename T>
Node* ...
```

But what the heck is this? What is this weird `Node` all about? This part of the C++ code is not inside a member function. You better have a global class, or something, named `Node`, or you'll be in big trouble.

Just because there happens to be some class or template that's defined, and it has an inner class named `Node`, well this means absolutely nothing, whatsoever. When some symbol name is used, in global scope, the compiler is not going to search every class for something that happens to have the same name. C++ does not work this way.

And that's why you must spell everything out:

```
template<typename T>
typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *
```

The "`template<typename T>`" stuff makes a grandiose entrance of a template parameter that's represented by symbol `T`, and `BinarySearchTree<T>::Node` spells everything out.

And the second part of this story, the only remaining question here, is what in blazes is that `typename` all about.

Well, [that's a long story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords), that you can read by yourself.

Comment: thank you a lot for the detailed answer! I figured as much until the "typename" part. This is where I was stuck. To be honest, I have no clue what typename really is, so I should probably go and figure out what that really is first.